# Parsing a string to a usable format and compare it to current date & time

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I'm trying to `Parse` a `string` that looks like this

```
20190903T114500,000
```

to a format and compare it to the *current time and date*. It's supposed to give an *alert*, when the date and time are only `5` minutes apart.

Yet I'm struggling with *every part* of that task. The format makes no sense, *I can't change* it because of that `"T"` in the middle.

Comment: See the documentation for [custom formatting for DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and the [ParseExact method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should `Parse` the given string (`source`) into `DateTime`. The format *does* have meaing (please, have a look at [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for reference). The only difficulty is `T` and `,` which can be *escaped*:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

string source = @"20190903T114500,000";

DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(
   source, 
  "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss','fff",     // here we escape both 'T' and comma ','
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Then find the difference:

```
TimeSpan diff = time - DateTime.Now;
```

Finally, alert if required:

```
if (diff.TotalMinutes >= -5.0 && diff.TotalMinutes <= 5.0) {
  //TODO: raise the alert here
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I'm tweaking the code right now and it seems to work!!! I finally understand it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First convert the string to date by using `DateTime.TryParseExact`. The format for the above example looks like `yyyyMMddTHHmmss,fff`. Once the string is converted to Date, you can use `DateTime.Now.Subtract` function to get the desired output. Check the below example.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(ParseDate("20190903T114500,000")).TotalMinutes);
    }

    private static DateTime ParseDate(string providedDate)
    {
        DateTime validDate;
        string[] formats = { "yyyyMMddTHHmmss,fff" };
        var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
          providedDate,
          formats,
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
          DateTimeStyles.None,
          out validDate);
        return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : DateTime.MinValue;
    }
```